# Apply custom function to pandas dataframe which relies on variable number of previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want an efficient solution to add a column to my table which calculates the sum of the absolute differences between this row's value and the values in the last N rows. e.g.

| number | new_col_2 | new_col_3 | new_col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | - | - | - |
| 11 | - | - | - |
| 12 | 3 | - | - |
| 9 | 5 | 6 | - |
| 8 | 5 | 8 | 10 |
| 12 | 7 | 7 | 8 |

```
new_col_2 => refers to calculating this for the last 2 rows. 
(12-10) + (12-11) => 3
(11-9) + (12-9) => 5

new_col_3 => refers to calculate this for the last 3 rows
(10-9) + (11-9) + (12-9) => 6
(11-8) + (12-8) + (9-8) => 8
```

and so on.

If N was a fixed number, I understand I could do this easily using:

```
df[new_col_N] = abs(df[number]-df[number].shift(N)) + abs(df[number]-df[number].shift(N-1)) + etc
```

But this assumes a fixed N. I want to write a function where I can add this column with N as an integer variable that can change.

Any idea what the most efficient way to do this is?

**Edit: Answer accepted below leads to the following solution for me:**

```
df[new_col_name] = df['number'].rolling(window=period+1).apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.abs(x[:-1]-x[-1])))
```

Comment: How do you get an insight from the accepted solution to arrive at your own solution ?   BTW, I run into errors for both the accepted solution and your solution.

Comment: No, I accepted BENY's solution. The key part of it is the numpy broadcasting. 
My solution works, I tested it in Excel comparing values generated by it and calculated manually on a large dataset.

Comment: I got an error `ValueError: -1 is not in range` for your solution.  Don't know why.  Got an error `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` for the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do numpy broad cast

```
n = 2 
a = df.number.values
df.loc[n:,'new'] = np.sum(np.abs(np.tril(np.triu(a-a[:,None],k=-n))),1)[n:]
df
Out[188]: 
   number new_col_2 new_col_3 new_col_4   new1
0      10         -         -         -    NaN
1      11         -         -         -    NaN
2      12         3         -         -    3.0
3       9         5         6         -    5.0
4       8         5         8        10    5.0
5      12         7         7         8    7.0
```

Comment: Is 'a' = the column number?

Comment: I used the same numpy broadcasting approach but used it with rolling() and apply() since your method gave me an error about something to do with multi-dimensional trays in bumpy being deprecated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BYZZav correct ~ that is column number but values ~